# Find the missing link

Tags: c#

Thee million men write down their name and the person to their left and the person on the far left throws out his paper.  Reconstruct the list.

A List takes a while. Don't try 3 million unless you have some time.

Up front we do NOT know the remaining man on left is 0.  That is what we are looking for. The remaining here is 0 as the was test data easy to create.

```
public static void TAOCPthreeMillionMenTest()
{
    int numberOfMen = 30000;  // test at less than 3 million or get killed
    List<PairInt> pairs = new List<PairInt>(numberOfMen);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfMen; i++)
    {
        pairs.Add(new PairInt(i, i + 1));
    }
    // shuffle left
    Random rand = new Random();
    int temp;
    int j;
    //shuffl up
    for (int i = numberOfMen - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        j = rand.Next(i + 1);
        if (i != j)
        {
            temp = pairs[i].Rght;
            pairs[i].Rght = pairs[j].Rght;
            pairs[j].Rght = temp;
            temp = pairs[i].Left;
            pairs[i].Left = pairs[j].Left;
            pairs[j].Left = temp;
        }
    }
    foreach (PairInt pair in pairs)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine(pair.Left + " " + pair.Rght);
        if (pair.Left == pair.Rght)
            Debug.WriteLine("pair.Left == pair.Rght");
    }
    Debug.WriteLine("");
    Debug.WriteLine(TAOCPthreeMillionManLeft(pairs));
    Debug.WriteLine("");
}
public static int TAOCPthreeMillionManLeft(List<PairInt> pairs)
{
    List<PairInt> lineEmUp = new List<PairInt>();
    int lineEmUpCountMax = 0;
    int lineEmUpCountMaxCount = 0;
    PairInt matchRght;
    PairInt matchLeft;
    int count = 0;
    foreach (PairInt pair in pairs)
    {
        count++;
        //Debug.WriteLine("new   " + pair.Left + " " + pair.Rght);
        //foreach (PairInt exist in lineEmUp)
        //{
        //    Debug.WriteLine("exist " + exist.Left + " " + exist.Rght);
        //}
        //Debug.WriteLine("");
        matchRght = lineEmUp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Rght == pair.Left);
        matchLeft = lineEmUp.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Left == pair.Rght);
        if (matchRght != null)
        {
            if (matchLeft != null)
            {
                matchRght.Rght = matchLeft.Rght;
                lineEmUp.Remove(matchLeft);
            }
            else
            {
                matchRght.Rght = pair.Rght;
            }
        }
        else if (matchLeft != null)
        {
            matchLeft.Left = pair.Left;
        }
        else
        {
            lineEmUp.Add(pair);
            if (lineEmUpCountMax < lineEmUp.Count)
            {
                lineEmUpCountMax = lineEmUp.Count;
                lineEmUpCountMaxCount = count;
            }
            //Debug.WriteLine("lineEmUp.Count " + lineEmUp.Count);
        }
    }
    // lineEmUp should have only one entry
    if (lineEmUp.Count != 1)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("");
        Debug.WriteLine("lineEmUp.Count != 1");
        foreach (PairInt pair in lineEmUp)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(pair.Left + " " + pair.Rght);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("");
    }
    return lineEmUp[0].Left;
}

public class PairInt
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Rght { get; set; }
    public PairInt(int left, int rght)
    {
        Left = left;
        Rght = rght;
    }
}
```

I tried a double dictionary but could not make it work.

Comment: Is this a programming-challage?

Comment: @t3chb0t Maybe some where but I read it as an example problem from a book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I get the problem, but one solution for reconstructing the original list (even 3.000.000 items) with a dictionary is:

```
public static void ReconstructList(List<PairInt> pairs)
{
    var leftRightDict = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Left, p => p.Rght);   
    var idx = 0;
    while (leftRightDict.TryGetValue(idx, out idx)) 
        Console.WriteLine(idx);
}
```

---

**Update:**

The following code gets the ID of the left-most men:

```
public static void ReconstructList(List<PairInt> pairs)
{
    var rightLefttDict = pairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Rght, p => p.Left);
    // just start with any men
    var right = pairs[0].Rght;
    while (rightLefttDict.TryGetValue(right, out right)) {}
    Console.WriteLine(right);
}
```

Comment: I don't follow this

Comment: That method reconstructs the initial created list. It creates a dictionary where the keys are the IDs of the mens who sit left and the values are the IDs of the mens who sit right. Starting with 0 (the most left men), it gets the id of the men right to the current one and use it to get the next men...

Comment: But this starts with you must know  what it is you are looking for.  We don't know the user on the far left is  idx = 0 - that is what we are looking for.  It was 0 as that was a convenient way for me to create the test case.

Comment: Ok, but then you can just start anywhere and go to the left-most men that has a value `Left` which does not exist as value for `Rght` for all `PaitInt` items. see updated answer

Comment: Ouch that was easy and makes sense.  I got too focused on one path.   I am going to leave it unanswered for a day just to get more feedback.